# HttpURLConnection getOutputStream class cast exception on Android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, outputstream

I'm trying to use `HttpURLConnection` to send and receive messages in an Android application. This code works fine in a java application, but when running on Android I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.okio.RealBufferedSink$1 cannot be cast to java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
```

The code where this occurs:

```
        URL url = new URL(destURI.toString());

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Set request properties and headers
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setRequestProperty(HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_TYPE_LS);
        con.setRequestProperty(HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH, new Integer(wrapperBytes.length).toString());
        con.setRequestMethod(METHOD_POST);

        // Set connect and read timeouts
        con.setConnectTimeout(timeoutInMillis);
        con.setReadTimeout(timeoutInMillis);

        // Write request content
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = (ByteArrayOutputStream) con.getOutputStream();
        out.write(wrapperBytes);
        out.flush();
```

I've looked at the android reference pages and these seem to say what I'd expect, `getOutputStream()` returns an `OutputStream`. This should then be able to be cast to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Where is the `RealBufferedSink` coming from? Why am I not getting an `OutputStream` back?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: just use this:
OutputStream out = con.getOutputStream();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = (ByteArrayOutputStream) con.getOutputStream();
```

is not recommended, 
you might try:

```
 OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: I don't think that is a valid constructor - there's `new ByteArrayOuputStream()` and `new ByteArrayOutputStream(int size)` but not one that takes the OutputStream parameter

Comment: @JLo237 I updated the answer, actually, it should be BufferedOutputStream